# Entering query to table SQL

Tags: sql

I'd like to know if it is possible to enter a query into a table, but the break key (') will
end the string prematurely - you can use double apostrophes but that would make the query void
when i would like to use it.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES ('INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES ('Something', 123, 'Something2')
```

Now as said, i could use double apostrophe to get 'Something' but that would make the query void and I would have to delete the apostrophes later on if I needed to use them.

What can I do?

Comment: Backslash doesn't work?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Check this fiddle. it is working example of your problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74c08/1

Comment: @AustinMullins: in (standard) SQL single quotes are **not** escaped with a backslash - in fact (standard) SQL does not put any special meaning to the backslash (`\`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work.

```
INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES ('INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES (''Something'', 123, ''Something2'')')
```

and in db you will have

```
INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES ('Something', 123, 'Something2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to insert an SQL statement into a table as a literal string? i.e. are you trying to insert the value `INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES ('Something', 123, 'Something2'` into a table with a single column, or are you trying to use a query result to insert values into the original table.

If you run the insert with double `'`s, the result will be a single  `'` in the database, so `INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES ('INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES (''Something'', 123, ''Something2''')` would insert the literal string `INSERT INTO (TABLE) VALUES ('Something', 123, 'Something2'`

But I'd question if this is what you're really after...

Comment: Yes, I deserved that -1.